# NSFetchedResultsController + UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource + CoreData - How to diff on the entire object?

Tags: core-data, uicollectionview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm trying to use some of the new diffing classes built into iOS 13 along with Core Data. The problem I am running into is that `controllerdidChangeContentWith` doesn't work as expected. It passes me a snapshot reference, which is a reference to a

```swift
NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, NSManagedObjectID>
```

meaning I get a list of sections/Object ID's that have changed.

This part works wonderfully. But the problem comes when you get to the diffing in the collection view. In the WWDC video they happily call

```swift
dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: true)
```

and everything works magically, but that is not the case in the actual API.

In my initial attempt, I tried this:

```swift
resolvedSnapshot.appendItems(snapshot.itemIdentifiersInSection(withIdentifier: section).map {
     controller.managedObjectContext.object(with: $0 as! NSManagedObjectID) as! Activity
}, toSection: .all)
```

And this works for populating the cells, but if data is changed on a cell (IE. the cell title) the specific cell is never reloaded. I took a look at the snapshot and it appears the issue is simply that I have references to these activity objects, so they are both getting updated simultaneously (Meaning the activity in the old snapshot is equivalent to the one in the new snapshot, so the hashes are equal.)

My current solution is using a struct that contains all my Activity class variables, but that disconnects it from CoreData. So my data source became:

```swift
var dataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, ActivityStruct>
```

That way the snapshot actually gets two different values, because it has two different objects to compare. This works, but it seems far from elegant, is this how we were meant to use this? Or is it just in a broken state right now? The WWDC video seems to imply it shouldn't require all this extra boilerplate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I ran into the same issue and I think I figured out what works:

There are two classes: `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource` and `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSourceReference`

From what I can tell, when you use the first, you're taking ownership as the "Source of Truth" so you create an object that acts as the data source. When you use the second (the data source reference), you defer the "Source of Truth" to another data source (in this case, CoreData).

You would instantiate a `...DataSourceReference` essentially the same way as a `...DataSource`:

```swift
dataSourceReference = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSourceReference(collectionView: collectionView, cellProvider: { (collectionView, indexPath, object) -> UICollectionViewCell? in
    let identifier = <#cell identifier#>
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath)

    <#cell configuration#>
            
    return cell
})
```

And then later when you implement the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`, you can use the following method:

```swift
func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChangeContentWith snapshot: NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshotReference)
{
    dataSourceReference.applySnapshot(snapshot, animatingDifferences: true)
}
```

---

I watched the WWDC video as well and didn't see this referenced. Had to make a few mistakes to get here. I hope it works for you!

Comment: The `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSourceReference` is just a bridged type from Objective-C. It has this notice in its documentation: `If you’re working in a Swift codebase, always use UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource instead.`. The same goes for `NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshotReference`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you try to use your models directly in snapshot and implement `Hashable` for them using properties that might change, such changes will appear as a pair of **deleted**&**inserted** items, because snapshot treats those `itemIdentifiers` as **stable identity**, meaning that it is not expected to ever change. In the event of changing identifier it is treated as if the old identifier was removed and a new one added. When applying such snapshot it will appear as item removing from the list and added back. Similar problem is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62267256/swift-diffabledatasource-make-insertdelete-instead-of-reload).

---

### Reloading items

Snapshot has `reconfiguredItemIdentifiers`, `reloadedItemIdentifiers` and `reloadedSectionIdentifiers` properties. These identifiers tell the **DataSource** which items have changed in a snapshot. (`reconfigured` would preserve existing cell, while `reloaded` will perform a full reload of the cell).

When you're using `NSFetchedResultsController` its delegate gives you a snapshot with all information filled, identifiers of managed objects that were changed will appear in `reloadedItemIdentifiers`.

Note that the snapshot is created relative to the `fetchRequest` you used in your `NSFetchResultsController`. If an object is changed in such a way that it no longer satisfies `fetchRequest.predicate` it will only appear as **deleted** item. And the same goes for when object changes in a way that it stars satisfying `fetchRequest.predicate` - the item will appear as **inserted**. This makes sense, but might be not obvious.

Lastly, snapshot only tracks identifiers of added/deleted/moved/changed items and doesn't store actual objects. When you apply snapshot, datasource will ask you to do the actual updates to the cell, you must fetch the actual object from data store and configure cell with this new object.